# How to share cookie between two different domain

Tags: cookies, webforms

i just do not know that is it at all feasible to share cookie between two different domain but when i need to share cookie between two sub domain then i do it below way

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookiename", "value");
cookie.Domain = "domain.com";

For forms authentication set this in web.config

<forms name=".ASPXAUTH" 
       loginUrl="login.aspx" 
       protection="All" 
       timeout="30" 
       path="/" 
       requireSSL="false" 
       domain="domain.com">
</forms>
```

Comment: do u have answer for your question now. i am also facing the same issue

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can use jQuery for that and only specify the domain

`$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { path: '/', domain: 'www.example.com' });`

Comment: i just really do not understand what u r trying to say...would u like to say in more detail.